# Can't Get Mac Mini to turn on - no screen, no beep, only the fan, power light, and optical drive noise

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini

I have an Intel-based Mac mini mid-2007 (Model A1176).  This is the computer my kids use so I don't use it regularly.  The computer had been working fine until one day my kids told me that it no longer works.  The computer will not boot up.  When I turn it on the fan turns, the white power light in the front turns on, and there is a sound that appears to be from the optical drive (rather than hard drive).  I don't get anything to the monitor, nor do I get any dings or other start up sounds from the computer.

Here is what I've tried thus far to no avail:
1) Swapped out the monitors early on since I figured that was my weak link - no change
2) Reset the PMU - no change
3) Tried to boot up from the System Disk - The mini loaded the dvd into the drive, but nothing else (I can't eject the disk so I can put it back)
3) Start up the computer in target mode connected to another mac - I tried this too, but I never received a chime or the disk show up on the other mac.

I'm about out of ideas apart from scraping the computer.  Does anyone have any ideas that I can try?  Again, nothing has been done to the computer in at least 6 months when I upgraded the RAM.  I'm also still on Leopard.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but one side issue you mentioned re: not being able to eject your DVD. If you hold down the mouse button while booting, an eject command is sent. This is a holdover from floppy disk days, but it still works with DVDs and CDs on the latest Macs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I can help solve the problem, but my previous experiences with a similar problem may help diagnose it.  My previous desktop would occasionally do this if I attempted to boot it within a few minutes of being shut down.  I eventually found with some certainty that this was a POST issue likely caused either by a bad power supply or motherboard.

Unfortunately, these parts may be difficult to swap in a Mac Mini.  If it is still under warranty, I would suggest throwing it Apple's way.

Comment: I'm afraid you may be right on the PS or MB.  It's out of warranty so it's probably not worth it to send to Apple.  I have Apple Care for my main machines, but I didn't bother with the Mac Mini.  Oh well...  at least it's not my Mac Pro :)

Answer (score 0):

did you drain the 'Flea Power'?

disconnect the power, press the power button for 20 seconds, reconnect the power and try again.

Comment: I did, but no luck.  I'm beginning to think that somehow the MB went out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While booting up hold CMD-OPT-P-R until you hear the boot-up gong 3 times. My Powermac does this all the time. This key combo always works.

Comment: Thanks for the key combo idea.  I finally broke down and took the computer to the Apple Store.  Dead Logic Board was the verdict.

Comment: Oh, well glad that you got the problem figured out. Sorry, but I can't help you with a hardware problem because I have never actually had a mac break myself. Are you under warranty?